# NoReverseMatch at / 'learning_logs' is not a registered namespace

Tags: python-3.x, django

I think i tired everything in trying to solve this problem.
I'm getting a NoReverseMatch i understand its from my "urls" but that's basically it, I was using url() instead of path().at the end of it all i just made a mess of my code.
**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse


from .models import Topic as TopicModel
from .forms import TopicForms


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
   """"the home page for learning app"""
   return render(request,'learning_logs/index.html')


def topics(request):

   topics = TopicModel.objects.order_by('date_added')
   context = {'topics' : topics}
   return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html',context)

def topic(request, topic_id):
   """show a single topic ans all its entries"""
   topic = TopicModel.objects.get(id=topic_id)
   entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('date_added')
   context = {'topic':topic, 'entries': entries}
   return render(request,'learning_logs/topic.html',context)

def new_topic(request):
   """add a new topic"""
   if request.method != 'POST':
       #no data submitted ; create a black form
       form = TopicForms
   else:
       #POST data submited ; process data
       if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_log:topics'))


   context = {'form': form }
   return render(request,'learning_log/new_topic.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
#defins URL patterns for learning log

from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.urls import path
app_name = 'learning_log'

urlpatterns = [
    #home page
    path('', views.index, name ='index'),
    #url(r'^$', views.index, name='index.html'),

    #show topics
    path('topics/',views.topics, name ='topics'),
   # url(r'^topics/$',views.topics, name='topics.html'),
    path('topics/<topic_id>',views.topic, name = 'topic'),
    #url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)\$',views.topic,name='topic.html'),
    path('topics/',views.new_topic, name = 'new_topic'),
    #url(r'^topics/$',views.new_topic, name='new_topic.html'),

]
```

**main urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls')),
    path('admin/',admin.site.urls),

]
```

**please anything I'm doing wrong plus any books or tutorials i can read because i think the book im using is outdated**

Comment: can you show your main urls.py?

Comment: @DiegoPuente I just did

Answer (score 0):

Your `app_name` inside the urls file is "learning_log" but it seems your html folders are in learning_log**s**. Maybe something to do with that? Also can you make sure the app_name exists in your `INSTALLED_APPS`?

I've done a Udemy course for Django which was good for me but they are not free if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

just add the include param called `namespace` in your main urls.py for the app.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('learning_logs.urls', namespace="learning_log")),
    path('admin/',admin.site.urls),

]
```

here you have the documentation of URLs namespaces: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces

If you don't want to set the namespace you must call the url like this: `reverse('topics')`